# Can i use closed source application for artworks or icon in my application for the showdown?

Tags: application-development

I want to develop an application for "ubuntu app showdown".
Can i use Closed Source Application for artworks or icons ? like Corel or Photoshop or etc.
(What if i use them with winehq in ubuntu?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as long as the icons you create are your own work. If you create new images you are the copyright holder and can do with them as you please. In this context photoshop or corel are legally no different from a pen and paper - adobe own the rights to photoshop's code, but not the rights to everything produced with it (if they did people would soon stop using it!).

Comment: Thanks. but what about artworks in application ? Can i use them too for artworks ?

Comment: If you mean taking icons from photoshop or anything else then it would depend on the license those artworks are released under. I'd be surprised if adobe released any of there icons in a way that would let you copy them, so the answer in that case would be no.

Comment: No I mean i make artworks and icons with photoshop and then export them to .png for example and use them in my application

Comment: That brings us back to the original answer. Any artwork you create yourself, using whatever tools, is yours and you are free to distribute it as you please - including as part of an open source software package.